# Regex that matches first part of a word and only parts of the remaining word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of bank names for mortgages. Sometimes they are followed with the abbreviation BENEF or BENEFICIARY. I need to write a regex that will find BENEF and BENEFICIARY because I want to delete those words from the bank name. However, I do NOT want to delete words like BENEFIT, BENEFITS, BENEFACTOR, BENEFACTORS, BENEFICIARIES, etc.

This doesn't work:

```
import re
bankname = re.sub(r'(BENEF)(ICIARY)?', '', bankname)
```

This does, but there has to be a more elegant solution:

```
import re
bankname = re.sub(r'(\bBENEF\b|\bBENEFICIARY\b)', '', bankname)
```

I'm just not seeing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `r'\bBENEF(?:ICIARY)?\b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\bBENEF(?:ICIARY)?\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1uC2X/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `BENEF` - a `BENEF` substring
- `(?:ICIARY)?` - an optional non-capturing group that does not store its value in a submatch and matches 1 or 0 repetitions of `ICIARY` (due to `?` quantifier)
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/seBGhq):

```
import re
s = "BENEFIT, BENEFITS, BENEFACTOR, BENEFACTORS, BENEFICIARIES BENEF BENEFICIARY"
print(re.sub(r"\bBENEF(?:ICIARY)?\b", "", s))
# => BENEFIT, BENEFITS, BENEFACTOR, BENEFACTORS, BENEFICIARIES
```

Comment: I put your code into the regex tester at regex101.com. While it matches BENEFICIARY, it doesn't match BENEF alone. I need it to do that too.

Comment: @RickColgan See https://regex101.com/r/q1uC2X/1  - you must have forgotten to set `g` flag ("global", multiple matching). I actually provided the link in my answer. I also provided a Python demo to prove the solution works as expected. It does not match `MYBENEF`, BTW.

Comment: @RickColgan You should be careful when testing pattern at the online regex testing sites, there are bugs and the way you define the patterns in the string literals may have an impact, so it is advised to test all your regexes in the *target* environment.